# To check if a string has all Unique Characters in C++

Tags: c++, string, duplicates

Am trying to find If a string has all Unique characters and below is my code, But I get the error "invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript" in the if statement of the function Unique char, can anyone tell me how to correct this

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
bool unique_char(char);

int main()
{
    char s;
    bool check;
    cout << "Enter any string" << endl;
    cin>>s;
    check = unique_char(s);
    if(check)
        cout<<"there are no duplicates";
    else
        cout<<"the string has duplicates";

    return 0;
}

// The if statement in this section has the error
bool unique_char(char s)
{
    bool check[256] = {false};
    int i=0;
    while (s != '\0')
    {
        if (check **[(int) s[i]]**)
            return false;
        else
        {
         check[(int) s[i]] = true;
         i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How many characters do you think you can fit into a single `char`?

Comment: A variable of type `std::string`, from the `<string>` header, can hold a text string of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass char array rather than a single char.

```
int main()
{
    char s[1000]; // max input size or switch to std::string
    bool check;
    cout << "Enter any string" << endl;
    cin>>s;
    check = unique_char(s);
    if(check)
        cout<<"there are no duplicates";
    else
        cout<<"the string has duplicates";

    return 0;
}

bool unique_char(char* s)
{
    bool check[256] = {false};
    int i=0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (check[(int) s[i]])
            return false;
        else
        {
         check[(int) s[i]] = true;
         i++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```